# Large WCF result sending in to Silverlight app

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I currently have a Silverlight app calling into a WCF service which returns roughly 7000 objects. We can get it to return roughtly 6500 objects but returning the whole set fails. It also allows us if we remove a property from the DTO but adding it back in causes failure.

Our client config is thus:

```
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="EchoWCFBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"></binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
```

Our server config is thus:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="simpleHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

We're using ChannelFactory<> to connect to the service and if we increase the maxReceivedMessageSize on the client it throws an exception on construction saying that it must be an int.

Comment: WCF service set up is HORRIBLE, and I lost a good couple of days to similar errors.  If you aren't getting complete exception information (i.e. you're getting the dreaded "NotFound" error), you should enable logging and you'll have more info then.  See SO article [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316201/silverlight-and-wcf-notfound-error] for answers on getting more info.  This blog: [http://softarchitect.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/software-architecture-debugging-in-silverlight-wcf/] also has useful info on logging that I used to view the insides of my exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with code which actually gave a nicer user experience. I split the list up into manageable blocks and sent them over the wire with separate client requests. With this I was able to provide a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>        
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"
   maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
   maxDepth="2147483647"
   maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
   maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```